# Cleaner way to keep a connection/session alive in discordgo?

Tags: go

I'm using the [github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo](https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo) package
and I've seen in the examples that the way to keep a connection or a "session" alive is to use the following:

```
<-make(chan struct{})
```

But it looks kinda messy, is this the best way of keeping it alive or is there another method.

Comment: Can you share full code?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a link to your example, so we can only guess. For example, my guess,

> the last bit of code in our main function:
>
> `<-make(chan struct{})`
>
> We're creating a channel that takes an empty struct that waits for
>   input. This is a SUPER hacky way of making our main function sit and
>   wait forever while not using any CPU.
>
> https://boostlog.io/@cuken/writing-a-simple-discord-bot-in-go-part-1-5ae6a1d647018500491f42bb

---

Have you tried this?

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
>
> ```
> select {}  // block forever
> ```